Validation accuracy can't increase above 70%
I am building a classifying model to predict images over 3 classes. The data is balanced, with 10.5k images for train ( 3.5k for each ), 3k validation images ( 1k each ).
I increased my validation accuracy at around 70%-75% but can't go further
I used a the keras_tuner.Hyperband to search for optimal hyperparameters, but the best I got from it is this model:
def build_model():
    """Builds a convolutional model."""

    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(80, 80, 3)),
      tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255)
    ])
   # 1st - filters 1 = 48
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=48,
            kernel_size=4,
            padding="same",
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))

    # 2nd - filters 192, kernel 4, pooling max, no dropout
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=192,
            kernel_size=4,
            padding="same",
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())


    #3rd - filters: 64, kernel - 5, maxpool dropout = 0.3
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters=256,
            kernel_size=5,
            padding="same",
        ))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1))
    # global avg pooling
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    # flatten - no hyperparametr
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    # dense layers: 2, NO REGULARIZERS
    # 1st layer: 288 units
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=288))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
       

    # 2nd dense: 192, 0.3 dropout, no regulraizers!!
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=192))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.3))

    # add last dense layer for num_classes:
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

    lr = 0.0010297

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr)
    model.compile(
        optimizer, loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

    return model

This resulted in around 0.73 val_accuracy, with no data_augumentation at all. The thing is that after getting to 0.7, both training and val were stuck there, pretty stable, not going further, not decreasing.
So I tried modifying the learning rate to use Cosine decay, switching to SGD as an optimizer, and trying some data_augumentation processes, and also making the model more complex so that the training_accuracy will grow more.
I came up with two of what I think are closest to a better model, even though the val_accuracy didn't increase:
For both of them, this was the cosine_decay lr scheduler and optimizer:
def lr_warmup_cosine_decay(
    global_step,
    warmup_steps,
    hold=0,
    total_steps=0,
    start_lr=0.0,
    target_lr=1e-2,
):
    # Cosine decay
    learning_rate = (
        0.5
        * target_lr
        * (
            1
            + ops.cos(
                math.pi
                * ops.convert_to_tensor(
                    global_step - warmup_steps - hold, dtype="float32"
                )
                / ops.convert_to_tensor(
                    total_steps - warmup_steps - hold, dtype="float32"
                )
            )
        )
    )

    warmup_lr = target_lr * (global_step / warmup_steps)

    if hold > 0:
        learning_rate = ops.where(
            global_step > warmup_steps + hold, learning_rate, target_lr
        )

    learning_rate = ops.where(global_step < warmup_steps, warmup_lr, learning_rate)
    return learning_rate


class WarmUpCosineDecay(schedules.LearningRateSchedule):
    def __init__(self, warmup_steps, total_steps, hold, start_lr=0.0, target_lr=1e-2):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_lr = start_lr
        self.target_lr = target_lr
        self.warmup_steps = warmup_steps
        self.total_steps = total_steps
        self.hold = hold

    def __call__(self, step):
        lr = lr_warmup_cosine_decay(
            global_step=step,
            total_steps=self.total_steps,
            warmup_steps=self.warmup_steps,
            start_lr=self.start_lr,
            target_lr=self.target_lr,
            hold=self.hold,
        )

        return ops.where(step > self.total_steps, 0.0, lr)

optimizer:
total_images = 10500
total_steps = (total_images // BATCH_SIZE) * EPOCHS
warmup_steps = int(0.1 * total_steps)
hold_steps = int(0.45 * total_steps)
schedule = WarmUpCosineDecay(
    start_lr=0.05,
    target_lr=1e-2,
    warmup_steps=warmup_steps,
    total_steps=total_steps,
    hold=hold_steps,
)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    weight_decay=5e-4,
    learning_rate=schedule,
    momentum=0.9,
)

1. No data augumentation, one more dense layer and no kernel_regularization
same model just repeat the 1st dense layer, with no dropout
# 0.73 val_accuracy, while training_accuracy went up to 0.9 for 40epochs

2. No data augumentation, one more dense layer and kernel_regularization=L2(0.01)
same as the first, just added kernel_regularization=L2(0.01) to the dense layers
# around 0.75 val_accuracy, while training_accuracy went up to 0.98 for 40epochs

So I saw this as an overfit and try to tweak the training data via some data_augmentation processes. At first I overshoot it, with too much augments, like this:
# simple random flip
random_flip = keras_cv.layers.RandomFlip()
augmenters = [random_flip]

# crop + resize
crop_and_resize = keras_cv.layers.RandomCropAndResize(
    target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
    crop_area_factor=(0.8, 1.0),
    aspect_ratio_factor=(0.9, 1.1),
)
augmenters += [crop_and_resize]


# adding random augumentations
rand_augment = keras_cv.layers.RandAugment(
    augmentations_per_image=3,
    value_range=(0, 255),
    magnitude=0.3,
    magnitude_stddev=0.2,
    rate=0.7,
)
augmenters += [rand_augment]


# adding random choice between cutmix and mixup
cut_mix = keras_cv.layers.CutMix()
mix_up = keras_cv.layers.MixUp()


cut_mix_or_mix_up = keras_cv.layers.RandomChoice([cut_mix, mix_up], batchwise=True)
augmenters += [cut_mix_or_mix_up]

But this resulted in low training_accuracy and jumping val_accuracy. Then I tried just two simple augments, like random_flip and random_zoom, but this again resulted in a very jumpy val_accuracy and low training_accuracy. The val_acc will go from 0.4 to 0.5 then again 0.45 then 0.6, totally unstable.
What should I do further? It seems like I'm somehow stuck between a stable model with maximum capacity of 0.7, and two overfitting models with a 0.7 validation accuracy at best
Confusion Matrix for the model:


Could you elaborate on the image dimensions? It might be that one class is relatively poor whereas the others are ok - consider looking at accuracy per class to identify what the model is struggling with.

The images are 80x80 color. I did plot the confusion Matrix for the validation data and for class 0 the accuracy is about 85-90 while class 1 is around 70 and for class 2, which is the worst, gets a ~60 accuracy

For the class 2 failures, do they tend to get confused with one particular class, or does it equally misclassify them into the other classes?

@MuhammedYunus The 2 classes get confused with each other more frequently, I will add the confusion matrix in the question

It seems like the net is confusing 1 with 2, and 2 with 1. This suggests the net is not able to distinguish between the classes. Some domain knowledge could help with understanding why they get mixed up, such as 'what are the pertinent differences between these classes' and 'on what scale are they most visible'.
It might help to use a larger kernel size at the input (the first conv layer) - something in the range 5 to 7. This will help the net look over a wider receptive field when differentiating between the classes. I think this would be especially important if the differences between 1 and 2 are on a more global scale.
I'd try combining this with stride=2 in order to down-sample the image and reduce the number of parameters.
Also, consider using only $3\times3$ kernels after the input layer. You can do this by replacing the kernel_size=4 layer with =3, and replacing the kernel_size=5 layer with two layers which both have kernel_size=3.
This will result in a net that uses fewer parameters, deployed in a more hierarchical and efficient way.
To mitigate overfitting, try growing the number of features more gradually. For example, you can still double the features at each step, but start smaller. So you might go 16, 32, 64, 128.
Change one thing at a time and see whether it results in an improvement.

I will try these. What do you mean by "larger kernel size at the input" ? You mean at the first conv layer after the Input and Rescale?

Yes, I meant the first conv layer.

I tried, got the first layer to 5 and 7 kernel, updated all other conv with kernel = 3, added strides=2, changed the features number for the conv layers. Trained it for 100 epochs so the rates get to converge. At first, the val_acc was jumping, fluctuating, but at the end, it was stable, around 0.67 while the training_accuracy was growing constantly and got to 0.99

Just to clarify...I meant the first conv is sized 7 with stride=2. The rest are sized 3 with stride=1. At the moment there's a ReLU after each batchnorm. Try removing those, i.e. just have 1 ReLU after each conv. Could try removing the first maxpool, because you're already downsampling the input with the strided conv. I'd disable dropout for now.
